# Add Fields To Entity From Another Bundle Symfony2/Doctrine

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, entity, bundle

So Here is the situation I have two Bundles, Bundle A and Bundle B

Bundle A has 2 Entities Entity A1 and Entity A2 
Bundle B has 2 Entities Enitiy B1 and Enitiy B2

I want to add new fields in A1 if Bundle B is activated.Also I want to make a relation ship between A1 and B1 for example. How Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add properties to a class from the outside. The only thing you can do is create an entity class `A1_extended` in the Bundle B, that inherits from the original `A1` class. But then you have to make sure that this extended class is used. Bundle A would have to provide a way to override the class that is used.

Comment: I have already tried that, but it throws A1 already exists while creating the schema, since they both have the same name. If I change the name however it works but then i'd have 2 tables not 1 where i want only 1 table A1, and A1_extended if bundle B is activated

Comment: Take a look at Doctrine inheritance: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: I did that, doesnt really help me cause what I need is not possible in doctrine and i am looking for a work around